# Vertical Lines in Table not showing in Dark Mode (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, formatting

I have a table in which each row has 5 `UILabel`s.

In the `UITableViewCell` class I set each `label.layer.borderWidth = 0.5`.

Then, in a table configuration function, I set `tableView.separatorColor = lineColor`.

The horizontal lines appear in the table but the vertical lines do not.  I've increased the borderWidth, changed colors, checked both portrait and landscape, but the vertical lines just do not appear.

Light: [image]

Dark: [image]

How do I display vertical lines separating the cells when in Dark Mode?

Comment: The default color is gray. what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I just want them visible.  I can set `lineColor` to anything I want, but they do not appear in any color or any borderWidth.